# Android filter resourse by screen size and density

Tags: android, android-layout

How I can filter the application resource according the screen size and density? 
I like to filter resource like this...

- SMALL SCREEN-HIGH DENSITY
- SMALL SCREEN-MEDIUM DENSITY
- SMALL SCREEN-LOW DENSITY
- NORMAL SCREEN-HIGH DENSITY
- NORMAL SCREEN-MEDIUM DENSITY
- NORMAL SCREEN-LOW DENSITY
- LARGE SCREEN-HIGH DENSITY
- LARGE SCREEN-MEDIUM DENSITY
- LARGE SCREEN-LOW DENSITY
- XLARGE SCREEN-HIGH DENSITY
- XLARGE SCREEN-MEDIUM DENSITY
- XLARGE SCREEN-LOW DENSITY

Let me know how can I make res folder structure according the above criteria.

Regards
Android_IT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) is full documentation about providing different resources for different screen sizes and densities

Answer (score 1):

In fact small screen and high density is very rarely

most device use only this

```
Small Screen - Low Density
Small Screen - Medium Density

Normal Screen - Low Density
Normal Screen - Medium Density
Normal Screen - High Density
Normal Screen - Extra-High Density

Large Screen - Low Density
Large Screen - Medium Density
Large Screen - High Density
Large Screen - Extra-High Density

Extra-Large Screen - Medium Density
Extra-Large Screen - High Density
```

but may be some changed in the future