# Drawable folders for different screen size and density combinations

Tags: android, drawable

What would be the drawable folders for

1. low density,medium screen
2. low density,large screen
3. low density,Xlarge screen
4. medium density,small screen
5. medium density,large screen
6. medium density,Xlarge screen

   and for tablets?

Comment: All I could find is this:
[Android-filter-resource-by-screen-size-and-density][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443053/android-filter-resourse-by-screen-size-and-density

Answer (score 5, accepted):

low density,medium screen

```
drawable-ldpi
```

low density,large screen

```
drawable-large-ldpi
```

low density,Xlarge screen

```
drawable-xlarge-ldpi
```

medium density,small screen

```
drawable-small-mdpi
```

medium density,large screen

```
drawable-large-mdpi
```

medium density,Xlarge screen

```
drawable-xlarge-mdpi
```

There are 14 drawables/layouts check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558534/do-i-need-14-different-layouts-to-support-all-android-devices) question

Comment: I created drawable-small-mdpi and put images into it. But eclipse graphical layout isn't seeing it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry Jagual, are you sure about the sixth one? I mean "drawable-mdpi" is eligible for large screen?

Comment: @VahidGhadiri thanks for pointing out that. I've edited my answer