# how to design the xml file coding for different screen size?

Tags: android, screen

[i read this link also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13068273/drawable-folders-for-different-screen-size-and-density-combinations?lq=1) I cannot understand how and where can i create different xml files.

I designed application for particular device. After that i was tested in basic android os version with small screen device and the output was looks like image i posted. How can i design for the different screen sizes. In xml layout its look like an arranged(ordered) format. when run in small screen device the position was changed. 
I want to modify and supports to all type of screen sizes. How can i achieve this. Help me friends.

Comment: `drawable-xxx` are folders in `res/` folder, you can see them there or create new for your screen

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17357682/how-can-i-made-the-layout-that-will-work-in-both-tablet-and-phone

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the best practice in designing your layouts is to use attributes like `Fill_Parent`, `Wrap_Content` , `Match_Parent`.

Try avoiding the use of explicitly defining the layout sizes and dimensions.

if you really want to do this way, you can define layouts for different screen sizes separately, and place them in their respective folders correspondingly.